# Many thanks to Martin Scharrer

Tags: discussion, moderation

TeX-sx left beta in 2011, and since then we have had a team of three moderators: me ([Joseph Wright](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/73/joseph-wright)), [Stefan Kottwitz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/213/stefan-kottwitz) and [Martin Scharrer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/2975/martin-scharrer). All of us have worked hard to make the community work, mainly doing the 'garbage collection' part of the moderators role with (luckily) little of the Big Stick work.

Moderation on TeX-sx remains quite a light task, but there is an amount of work to do. Martin has over recent times found that real life has kept him busy, and has decided that it's time to hand over the baton. Stefan and I could manage the workload on our own, but there are benefits to having a team of three people: there's sometimes a need to discuss complex cases, and having a few people helps.

So there will be an election soon for a new moderator: the Powers That Be will be announcing and organising. Here, I'd just like to record Stefan and my thanks to Martin for his work on the site over the last decade, and wish him all the best in the future.

Comment: thanks @martin (even though the ping won't work)

Answer (score 50):

A very ***big*** thanks to Martin who beat me in the race for the first “Legendary” badge, which he earned on 11 November 2011, three weeks earlier than I.

Although he stopped writing answers a while ago, his contribution to the site and to the TeX world has always been great, both as a TeXpert and as a moderator.